# Is there a away to detect the event when iOS device goes to sleep mode (when the screen gets blackened)?

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi, sleep-mode

I wanted to detect two events :

1. Device gets locked/unlocked.
2. Device goes to sleep and the screen blackens.

First one I have been able to achieve here:
[Is there a way to check if the iOS device is locked/unlocked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229955/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-the-ios-device-is-locked-unlocked/14271472#14271472)

Now I want to detect the second event, is there any way to do it ?

Comment: Is this question about private apis for iPhone?

Comment: Anything will suffice, I don't intend to submit my app on App Store.

Answer (score 22):

You basically already have the solution, which I'm guessing you found from one of my recent answers :)

Use the `com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen` event.

There are multiple events that occur when the screen blanks, but this one should suffice:

```
CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter(), //center
                                NULL, // observer
                                hasBlankedScreen, // callback
                                CFSTR("com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen"), // event name
                                NULL, // object
                                CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);
```

where the callback is:

```
static void hasBlankedScreen(CFNotificationCenterRef center, void *observer, CFStringRef name, const void *object, CFDictionaryRef userInfo)
{
    NSString* notifyName = (__bridge NSString*)name;
    // this check should really only be necessary if you reuse this one callback method
    //  for multiple Darwin notification events
    if ([notifyName isEqualToString:@"com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen"]) {
       NSLog(@"screen has either gone dark, or been turned back on!");
    }
}
```

---

**Update:** as @VictorRonin said in his comment below, it should be easy to keep track yourself whether the screen is currently **on** or **off**.  That allows you to determine whether the `hasBlankedScreen` event is occurring when the screen goes on or off.  For example, when your app starts, set a variable to indicate that the screen is on.  Also, any time any UI interaction occurs (button pressed, etc.), you know the screen must currently be on.  So, the next `hasBlankedScreen` you get should indicate that the screen is **off**.

Also, I want to make sure we're clear on the terminology.  The device *locks* when the screen automatically darkens due to a timeout, or when the user manually presses the power button.  This happens regardless of whether the user has a **Passcode** configured.  At that time, you will see the `com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen` and the `com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete` events.

When the screen turns back on, you will see `com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen` once again.  But, you will not see `com.apple.springboard.lockstate` until the user has actually unlocked the device with a swipe (and maybe a passcode).

---

**Update 2:**

There's yet another way to do this.  You can use an alternate set of APIs to listen for this notification, and also [get a state variable](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/DarwinNotify/Reference/reference.html) when the notification comes:

```
#import <notify.h>

int status = notify_register_dispatch("com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen",
                                      &notifyToken,
                                      dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(int t) {
                                          uint64_t state;
                                          int result = notify_get_state(notifyToken, &state);
                                          NSLog(@"lock state change = %llu", state);
                                          if (result != NOTIFY_STATUS_OK) {
                                              NSLog(@"notify_get_state() not returning NOTIFY_STATUS_OK");
                                          }
                                      });
if (status != NOTIFY_STATUS_OK) {
    NSLog(@"notify_register_dispatch() not returning NOTIFY_STATUS_OK");
}
```

and you will need to keep an *ivar*, or some other **persistent** variable, to store the notification token (do not just make this a local variable in the method that registers!)

```
int notifyToken;
```

You should see the `state` variable, obtained via `notify_get_state()`, toggle between 0 and 1, which will let you distinguish between screen on and off events.

Although [this document is very old](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SpringBoard.app/Notifications), it does list which notification events have an associated state that can be retrieved via `notify_get_state()`.

**Warning:** [see this related question for some complications with this last technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14820249/119114)

Comment: I have already tried this, turns out, this notification comes in both the scenarios, when device goes to sleep and when device awakes from the sleep.:   
Jan 16 18:48:53 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0 
Jan 16 18:48:53 unknown Myapp[1921] <Warning>: Darwin notification NAME = com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen
an 16 18:50:29 unknown SpringBoard[15] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Jan 16 18:50:29 unknown Myapp[1921] <Warning>: Darwin notification NAME = com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen

Comment: You can keep a state variable, whether a device is asleep now or awake.

Comment: Do I notice correctly that my app will not receive lockstate or lockcomplete notifications if it is already in the background when the lock action occurs?

Comment: @SpencerWilliams, not necessarily.  If you just press Home to background your app, assuming your app .plist does not specify that it exits on suspend, then you will get the notifications.  Now, as with anything, there are limits on how much time your app gets in the background, so you may have to fiddle with things if you want to get these notifications indefinitely.  That's really another question, and depends on whether we're talking about a jailbreak app or not.  But, fundamentally, Darwin notifications don't stop just because you've entered the background.

Comment: @SpencerWilliams, also take careful note of the last parameter I pass when I register for the notifications.  If you aren't using `CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately`, then you very well might not see notifications when your app is in the background.

Comment: I am using `CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately`, but it seems my app doesn't receive the notifications if it's not in the foreground when the phone is locked, ie if another app is in use and the lock button is pressed, my app doesn't know the device is now locked (without polling periodically)

Comment: @SpencerWilliams, hmmm.  Works for me.  I think you'd probably need to post a new question, and fully list your code, and use case description.  Thanks.

Comment: @Everybody: Please look at this question, because it explains some potential pitfalls with this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820249/getting-state-for-system-wide-notifications-in-ios-and-os-x

Comment: @nate : Is there any public API to achieve the same?

Comment: @SunilAdhyaru, The answer above really **is** using Public APIs. `CFNotificationCenterAddObserver()` is public on iOS. The string name of the event is *undocumented*. But, it's not actually private. You should be able to use this code in an App Store app. I haven't tested it in a while though, so make sure it still woriks.

Comment: @mcfedr, these APIs are public, so you should be fine with app store approval. The string `com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen` is *undocumented*, which is different than being a *private* API. So, iOS could change and it could stop working in a future release. But, obviously, it's been there for years now.

Comment: Apple App Store rule changed in 2018 and now rejects apps that use `com.apple.springboard.hasBlankedScreen`. Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: @WilliamGrand this question was explicitly not for the App Store, but your comment is a good one for others. If someone was so inclined, obfuscation might get around that "problem" ;)

Comment: This is not allowed by apple anymore. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/76608

Answer (score 1):

You can also subscribe for a notification: "com.apple.springboard.lockstate" and use API [SBGetScreenLockStatus](http://www.marekbell.com/sbgetscreenlockstatus/) to determine status whether device is locked or not.

Comment: How to call and use it? actually I only want to detect the event when the screen  blackens i.e. screen transitions from on/off. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Info: Its not for a jailbroken device.

Comment: First notification is used with the same code, which Nate wrote. SBGetScreenLockStatus is described in linked article. These events I added as an answer for "Device gets locked/unlocked". And it works on non jailbroken device.

Comment: @Everybody: Please look at this question, because it explains some potential pitfalls with this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820249/getting-state-for-system-wide-notifications-in-ios-and-os-x