# Is there any notification that indicates iOS will put the device into a "sleep” state?

Tags: ios, iphone

I wonder whether the iOS sends a notification to apps that indicates the system will put the device into a "sleep” state. Because I want my app to do something when the device is in "sleep" state.

Comment: What do you mean with "sleep" state?

Comment: I think "sleep" = "locked" screen ;)

Comment: Yes, "sleep" = "locked" screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" is the notification that I used to fix my problem.

To receive "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" notification , I used  CFNotificationCenterAddObserer in applicationDidFinishLaunching.(It is said to a private api~)

However, if my app is running in background, it cannot receive the notification. To fix this problem, I added UIBackgroundModes(= audio) to play mute audio consequently. At last, the app works well.

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "NO". You can only track application state not device state.

Answer (score 0):

Good Answer :

> I managed to receive "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" notification
>   using CFNotificationCenterAddObserer. However, if my app is running in
>   background, it cannot receive the notification. To fix this problem, I
>   added UIBackgroundModes(= audio) to play mute audio consequently. At
>   last, the app works well.

sophia

Notification:

```
   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
        NSLog(@"Device state: %@", state);
        switch (state) {
            case UIApplicationStateActive:
                /* ... */
                break;

        case UIApplicationStateInactive:
            /* Device was/is locked  */
            break;
        case UIApplicationStateBackground:
            /* User pressed home button or opened another App (from an alert/email/etc) */
            break;
    }
}
```

Enum :

```
UIApplicationState - The running states of an application

typedef enum {
    UIApplicationStateActive,   
    UIApplicationStateInactive,
    UIApplicationStateBackground
}
UIApplicationState

Constants

UIApplicationStateActive - The application is running in the foreground and currently receiving events. Available in iOS 4.0 and later.

UIApplicationStateInactive - The application is running in the foreground but is not receiving events. This might happen as a result of an interruption or because the application is transitioning to or from the background.

UIApplicationStateBackground - The application is running in the background.
```

Sources : [Is it possible to distinguish between locking the device and sending an app to background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754317/is-it-possible-to-distinguish-between-locking-the-device-and-sending-an-app-to-b)

Comment: Maybe I was't make it clear. I mean UIApplicationState is the app's state, not the device's. Even though My app is already in background, the device is still not in sleep state.

Comment: It's the difference between StateInactive (locked) and StateBackground (just app sleeping).

Comment: I managed to receive "com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete" notification using CFNotificationCenterAddObserer. However, if my app is running in background, it cannot receive the notification. To fix this problem, I added UIBackgroundModes(= audio) to play mute audio consequently. At last, the app works well. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok, I edit the post with your answer ;) Or you can post your answers and validate it. Because your question is still unanswered :/

Answer (score 0):

when device will go to inactive state it send a notification

`- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application`

This method should implement in application delegate. It will invoke automaticlaly when does goes to inactive state. It also invoke when you receive a call

Comment: What you are saying is i tHink it is private API. You can refer to the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352228/is-there-a-away-to-detect-the-event-when-ios-device-goes-to-sleep-mode-when-the

Answer (score 0):

No, the only notification may fulfill your need is `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`, but it will also be posted when

user pull down the notification center

there comes an alarm clock ringing

an push notification showing in an alert view.