# NSNotificationCenter Add Observer not working in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsnotificationcenter, openurl, notificationcenter

I am working a two applications in which one application get invoked by other application. If one of the application has been quited (Neither not in foreground or background), `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:` was not working for very time time. If the application running in background, then every thing working as expected. I dont what going on. Some one please give me guide lines.

Comment: An NSNotificationCenter object can deliver notifications only within a single program. If you want to post a notification to other processes or receive notifications from other processes, use an instance of NSDistributedNotificationCenter.

Comment: I agree with KudoCC.  See [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527189/can-nsnotificationcenter-be-used-between-different-apps-to-communicate).

Comment: @KudoCC, Thank you the new idea. But i used `NSNotificationCenter` in the single application only. i wrote postNotification in appdelegte calss. But very first time (at time of installation), this notification class wont get called. This is my problem.

Comment: @KudoCC `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`is belongs to OSX right? iam looking for iOS

Comment: Yes, you can look at that link as Michael suggested.